# Pro*C Executable size change

Tags: sql, unix, proc

In my new project I have to deal with some Pro*C code and as a part of the project require to compile the entire code as there is a minor change in a header file. Now, to incorporate the changes I will have or recompile the entire application code, which I did. However the sizes of the new executable do not match the old ones, even for the code where the header file is not used. 
Can someone help ?

Answer (score 1):

Why do you think that even if you make some changes to the code, the executable will be of same size ? It can vary. Please check if the changes you made to the code are not making any difference to the existing functionality of the code rather than checking the size of the exe file.

Comment: Then i guess there is nothing to worry. As far as the code is doing what its intended to do, there must not be any issue.